# Iterate over a numpy array and call a method

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I have a problem. I want to transform the date from `'2008-09-24'` to `'24.09.2008'`. What I got is `<function <lambda> at 0x000001CD2B9CE820>`. How could I loop through the `host_since` and transform the date?

```
host_since = npListings[:,4].astype(np.datetime64) 
# host_since = 
['2008-09-24' '2009-12-02' '2009-11-20' '2010-03-23' '2010-05-13'
 '2010-05-13' '2010-05-25' '2010-07-23' '2009-12-22' '2010-08-08']

get_cubes = lambda x: [datetime.strptime(d, '%y-%m,%d').strftime('%d.%m.%Y') for d in range(host_since.shape[0])]
print(get_cubes)

[OUT]
<function <lambda> at 0x000001CD2B9CE82
```

What I want is get_cubes =
['24.09.2008' ... '08.08.2010'] # should be also a numpy array

Comment: You wrote a function. You call it with `get_cubes()`. But I see no point to it and you may as well do `get_cubes = <the list comphrehension>`.

Comment: The `lambda` defines a function that takes one argument.  That argument, `x` should be used in the function, and provided when called `get_cubes(something)`.  On a different matter, for datetime string conversion like this, `numpy` does not help at all.  You might as well be working a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Reti43 mentioned, you might as well skip the lambda altogether.

```py
cubes = [datetime.strptime(str(host_since[i]), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d.%m.%Y') 
             for i in range(host_since.shape[0])]
print(cubes)
```

Note: If the data in your commented-out `host_since` variable matches what's actually in your numpy array, you'll want to change your `strptime` format to `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: With that I got the following: `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question. Updated answer :)

Comment: @animuson out of curiosity - why did you deleted this answer and then undelete it? :)

Comment: @user17242583 Deletion and undeletion events schedule a user for a reputation recalc, which will usually fix [weird issues with your reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371401/account-reputation-issues).

Comment: Aha! I see. That must've been what fixed it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

2 points:

- Looking at the dates you include as an example, in the `strptime` function you have the wrong format, which should be `%Y-%m-%d` and not `%y-%m,%d`
- `for d in range(host_since.shape[0])` iterates integer numbers, right? So how does the `strptime` work then?
- We are clearly starting from the assumption that all the string dates are in the correct parseable format - note that, if that is not the case, a `ValueError` will the thrown by `strptime`, so maybe some sanity check is needed as well.

I have rewritten your code as follows:

```
host_since =np.array(\
['2008-09-24', '2009-12-02', '2009-11-20', '2010-03-23', '2010-05-13',
'2010-05-13', '2010-05-25', '2010-07-23', '2009-12-22', '2010-08-08'])

cubes = [datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d.%m.%Y') for d in host_since]

print(cubes)
```

If your want to use `range`, in my view you should write as follows:

```
cubes = [datetime.strptime(host_since[d], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d.%m.%Y') for d in range(host_since.shape[0])]
print(cubes)
```

As stressed above, using a lambda function here is unnecessary.